Networkx remove_from_nodes <= 2 gives unexpected behavior: removing randomly?
I’m trying to graph a network based on some interactions. I want to remove nodes that have a degree smaller than or equal to 2. So here is my code.
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(['player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4', 'player5', 'player6', 'player7' ])
G.add_edges_from([('player1', 'player2'), ('player1', 'player3'), ('player1', 'player4'), ('player1', 'player6'), ('player3', 'player2'), ('player3', 'player7'), ('player3', 'player4')])
G.degree

I get that:
DegreeView({'player1': 4, 'player2': 2, 'player3': 4, 'player4': 2, 'player5': 0, 'player6': 1, 'player7': 1})

Expected.
Then I perform the following:
nodes_to_remove = [node for node in G.nodes if G.degree(node) <= 2]
G.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)
G.degree

And it gives me that:
DegreeView({'player1': 1, 'player3': 1})

The output of nodes_to_remove is ['player2', 'player4', 'player5', 'player6', 'player7'] when it should actually be ['player1', 'player3'].
Anyone has an explanation?
I say "randomly" because when I switch around >= 2 or == 2 it never gives me the expected output… So I am quite confused.

I don't understand your problem - the nodes that were removed were precisely those with a degree less than or equal to 2, just as you requested.

I think I got it when I tried to respond to your message. The remove_nodes_from() does indeed remove the correct nodes. What I'm missing is that it changes (obviously) the degree of the remaining nodes? I was expecting degrees of nodes to be changed, but now it makes sense (if that’s the reason).

Then, what I want to achieve is that when plotting the graph, I do not want to have the nodes that have 2 or less degree in the graph. Is this possible?

You could have a loop that repeatedly finds the low-degree nodes, and removes them (for as long as any such nodes are found).  That would completely eliminate this example graph, but there are certainly graphs where some nodes would survive.

Is there no function or method that would do that properly? Because, as you said, repeatedly removing nodes with degree <=2 makes dynamically changes the degree of other nodes. What I am looking for though is purely graphic. I do not want to see those kinds of isolated nodes (degree <=2 but /= 0) on the graph. I’ll create another question, because it is becoming off topic.

Are you sure that degree <= 2 is really the condition you want?  I wouldn't describe a degree 2 node as "isolated" - such nodes could form a ring of arbitrary size, or be the only connection between two components of the graph.

I created a new question where I explain a bit more in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78486218/networx-and-ipysigma-how-to-remove-isolated-nodes-of-degree-2-on-graph

It is usually better and strongly recommended to edit an existing question, rather than creating a new question.
